# Circuit using LTC3108, inductor selection

Tags: circuit-design, inductor

I want to design a circuit using the LTC3108 low voltage step-up converter. The data sheet (pg.18 -Peltier-Powered Energy Harvester for Remote Sensor Applications-) calls for a LPR6235-752SMLB inductor. Since the supplier that I'm using doesn't have that part in stock, so I have to find another part. Can I use this part: https://www.arrow.com/en/products/b953as-7r5np3/murata-manufacturing ?

Regards,
Aslak

Answer (score 1):

The LPR6235-752SMLB is a coupled inductor with a 100:1 turns ratio. The arrow part is just a simple inductor (one winding) and it is not remotely compatible.

> Can I use this part

Not in this design (See T1): -

[image]

Comment: I cant seem to find any other relating products. Care to give me hint?

Comment: @user3635319 this site bars questions that specifially ask for where a component can be found. Try other suppliers is my only answer and BTW, I have no more idea than you how to track one down and given that you could be on the planent Jupiter, there's even less chance of my help being useful.

Answer (score 0):

no

It is not a couple inductor 1:100 ratio